# Custom Post Type Archives by Year & Month?

Tags: custom-post-types, archives, date, custom-post-type-archives, wp-get-archives

How do you display the archives of a Custom Post Type by Year & Month?

Comment: My solution below works if you are using < WP 4.4, but since the release of WP 4.4, wp_get_archives() FINALLY supports custom post types: https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_get_archives/

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Yes, you can.
All you need is make a filter for `wp_get_archives();` so it accepts `post_type` parameter:

```
function my_custom_post_type_archive_where($where,$args){  
    $post_type  = isset($args['post_type'])  ? $args['post_type']  : 'post';  
    $where = "WHERE post_type = '$post_type' AND post_status = 'publish'";
    return $where;  
}
```

then call this:

```
add_filter( 'getarchives_where','my_custom_post_type_archive_where',10,2);
```

Whenever you want to display archive by custom post type, just pass the post_type args:

```
$args = array(
    'post_type'    => 'your_custom_post_type',
    'type'         => 'monthly',
    'echo'         => 0
);
echo '<ul>'.wp_get_archives($args).'</ul>';
```

Comment: Did you try this solution? It correctly fetches the list of months with a post from your CPT and the number of posts, but the links are useless. Clicking them takes you to the month for the whole site, not for the CPT.

Comment: After some digging (see Tom Nowell's answer below), I gave up on monthly archives for custom post types. Instead, I used a post category, and changed my permalink structure to `/%category%/%year%/%monthnum%/%postname%/`. Then, it might be possible using a hook similar to above, to modify the links to start with `/%category%/` instead of just the date.

Comment: Question on this. This creates urls like: `mysite.com/2013/04` but this leads to a 404. The custom post type is available at: `mysite.com/cats` which makes me think `mysite.com/cats/2013/04` would be what the link should be, but this also resolves to a 404. How do you get the archive links to work?

Comment: Even better, there is finally plugin to deal with this missing functionality in WordPress. It was created by a core contributor trying to fix this issue in the core. The plugin is provided to get us through until the issue is properly addressed in the core. https://wordpress.org/plugins/archives-for-custom-post-types/

Answer (score 6):

You don't, the official line from the Wordpress developers was that custom post types weren't intended to do the job of normal ordinary posts, and that if you need post archives of dates etc, then you're not doing things correctly, and you're better off using post formats etc..

Custom post types are intended for web applications etc, whereas doing something such as setting up a custom post type that acts as a secondary or parallel blog with a different name, e.g. blog vs news, with the same abilities, is not what the feature was intended for, and would mean other technical issues arising from its implementation.

If you are still insistent on this, and simply using custom taxonomies and post formats is not enough, you could add rewrite rules in functions.php and redirect year/month archives in certain URLs to the post archive page, and then check on the custom post archive page if you've specified variables in your rewrite rules and load a different template, making sure in your rewrite rules to set the appropriate values.

Comment: It does seem a bit odd that they would only go so far with this functionality. Can you give me an example of how custom posts should be used?

Comment: Custom posts should be used for anything that isn't covered by the scope of pages and blog posts ( or blog posts with a different name but work the same, e.g. articles/news/diary/etc )

Examples of correct uses of custom posts include: events, menus, locations, forms, logs, etc

Comment: Custom posts are basically the means of producing web apps, they're not the means of duplicating the post menu in the backend for easier editing ( and such a use would make wordpress much slower and be more of a task than you realise to do )

Comment: UUUUUgh. This is the correct answer to the question tragically. I can't believe that the explanation above is based on "we shouldn't have date URLs for CPTs" though, it is almost definitely "Date URLs for CPTs are too complicated" that is driving the actual decision not to implement. CLEARLY there are cases where people would want date archives for a custom post type, you can't make that obvious desire dissapear by pointing out post formats.

Comment: I have to strongly disagree. Custom post types are meant to be used for whatever you want them to be used for, no where in the Codex does it say they are for "web apps". Also, you may very well need a "news" section which has it's own custom taxonomy and you'd want archives for those. Or even the suggested "events" type, which I agree are a perfect use for CPTs, but again those easily could need date based archives.

Comment: A news section suggests either a post format or a taxonomy indicating you have classified a post as news. A custom post type is not necessary for such a thing. Eitherway I sense that your definition of a web app may not be the same as mine, I will simply define my interpretation in this context as anything that is not a static page, or a blog post, that requires a post like representation of content, and would defer you to the WordPress core developer who originally stated this ( Probably Otto or Nacin )

Comment: Indeed we definitely define web apps differently. The good news is Jack Lenox from Automattic has a plugin that will now enable archives for CPTs, [see my answer below](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/173810/17461). Thus we can now finally easily create date archives for things like "Events" which really could use this functionality.

Comment: I guess the official line from the WordPress developers has changed :) ... This is now in the core.

Answer (score 5):

***EDIT*** -> while this answer still works for < WP4.4, since 4.4 support for Custom Post Types is now included in `wp_get_archives()`

---

There finally is a simple, quick and easy solution for date based archives of Custom Post Types in WordPress! This has been a long standing issue that is [recorded here](https://core.trac.wordpress.org/ticket/21596) in the WP Core Trac.

It has yet to be solved but one of the contributors to the Trac has posted a [simple plugin in GitHub](https://github.com/jacklenox/archives-for-custom-post-types) that will enable you to have date based archives for CPTs.

After installing this plugin, or adding the code for your functions manually you case use archives for CPTs as such:

`<?php wp_get_archives_cpt( 'post_type=custom_post_type' ); ?>`

Note this new function `wp_get_archives_cpt` works the same as the standard `wp_get_archives` so you can use any of the regular arguments it accepts. However, it simply adds the ability for you to be able to add a custom post type name argument.

Answer (score 2):

Not enough reputation to add this to taiken's answer sorry.

However wanted to add that his answer did work for me, however the links were in the 'localhost/date/2010' format. Whereas I needed 'localhost/postslug/2010' format. I was able to fix this by using a string replace on the output of wp_get_archives.

So depending on how your permalinks are set this code will fix the 404 problem and redirect the links to the custom post type permalink structure:

```
$yearly_archive = wp_get_archives(array( 'type' => 'yearly', 'post_type' => '<your post type name>', 'echo' => '0') );
$blog_url = get_bloginfo('url');
echo str_replace(($blog_url . '/date'), ($blog_url . '<your post type slug>'),$yearly_archive);
```

Answer (score 2):

Can't add to takien's post so here's what I ended up having to do:

**functions.php**

```
add_action('init', 'my_year_archive_rewrites');  
function my_year_archive_rewrites() {   
    add_rewrite_rule('resource/news/([0-9]{4})/page/?([0-9]{1,})/?', 'index.php?post_type=news&year=$matches[1]&paged=$matches[2]', 'top');
    add_rewrite_rule('resource/news/([0-9]{4})/?', 'index.php?post_type=news&year=$matches[1]', 'top');
}

add_filter('getarchives_where', 'my_custom_post_type_archive_where', 10, 2);
function my_custom_post_type_archive_where($where,$args){  
    $post_type = isset($args['post_type']) ? $args['post_type'] : 'post';  
    return "WHERE post_type = '$post_type' AND post_status = 'publish'";
}

add_filter('year_link', 'my_year_link');
function my_year_link($link) {
    global $wp_rewrite;

    if(true) { // however you determine what archive you want
        $link = str_replace($wp_rewrite->front, '/resource/news/', $link);
    }

    return $link;
}
```

**Calling wp_get_archives()**

```
wp_get_archives(array('post_type'=>'news', 'type'=>'yearly'));
```

Comment: See his is your first answer. Just a tip when answering questions, don't just add code or for that matter links. Although your code might work, it is always nice to know what your code does and why it should work. Otherwise your answer is nicely formatted. +1 for that